# Laravel 5.1 SES Integration

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.1, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

I'm trying to set up AWS SES integration with my Laravel 5.1 app.  I have been research different ways to use the SES integration include SQS.  But reading the laravel documentation - it says enter the values for

```
'key' => 'your-ses-key',
'secret' => 'your-ses-secret'
```

However, I haven't been able to find a place in the SES console to generate either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I finally found some information.  It seems like it requires the Amazon AWS key.  Different options can be found at the URL below http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-credentials.html?shortFooter=true